# Power pivot feature in SharePoint 2019

Tags: content-type, 2019, powerpivot, features, sharepoint-administration

We migrated from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2019, and although the Power Pivot feature was active in 2013, we did not reinstall it during the migration. As a result, we are facing a major problem.

When attempting to create a new subsite in SharePoint using a template, an error message is displayed indicating that a content type has an incorrect name. This issue is related to Power Pivot, and the content type cannot be deleted since its feature is not available in our new SharePoint environment.